# Why is my UIImage not set propely in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, mkmapview

I am using `MKMapSnapShotter`, but when I set a break point on `return finalImage` , I can see the value is just an empty `ObjectiveC.NSObject`, instead of `UIImage`.

```
 func getIMG() -> UIImage{
        var finalImage =  UIImage();
        let imageOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions();
        imageOptions.region = mapView.region;
        imageOptions.size = mapView.frame.size;
        imageOptions.showsBuildings = true;

        let imgMap = MKMapSnapshotter(options: imageOptions);
        imgMap.start(completionHandler: { (imageObj: MKMapSnapshot?, Error) -> Void in
            if(Error != nil){
                print("\(Error)");
            }else{
                finalImage = imageObj!.image;
            }

        });

        return finalImage;

    }
```

My map loads correctly, etc, so the problem must be here. Also, what is the quickest and easiest way to view the image for testing purposes ? (I don't want to have to design a imageView, etc just to see the image it produces).

Cheers

UPDATE:

```
func getIMG( completion: @escaping (UIImage)->() ){
        var finalImage =  UIImage();
        let imageOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions();
        imageOptions.region = mapView.region;
        imageOptions.size = mapView.frame.size;
        imageOptions.showsBuildings = true;

        let imgMap = MKMapSnapshotter(options: imageOptions);
        imgMap.start(completionHandler: { (imageObj: MKMapSnapshot?, Error) -> Void in
            if(Error != nil){
                print("\(Error)");
            }else{
                finalImage = imageObj!.image;
            }
            completion(finalImage);

        });

    }
```

-

```
  map.getMapAsIMG{ (image) in
        print(image);
    };
```

Note: compiler needed me to use @escape ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not return from function that use closure, so you also use closure with your function.

```
func getIMG(completion: (UIImage) -> ()) {

    var finalImage =  UIImage();
    let imageOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions();
    imageOptions.region = mapView.region;
    imageOptions.size = mapView.frame.size;
    imageOptions.showsBuildings = true;

    let imgMap = MKMapSnapshotter(options: imageOptions);
    imgMap.start(completionHandler: { (imageObj: MKMapSnapshot?, error) -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            print("\(Error)");
        }else{
            finalImage = imageObj!.image;
        }
        completion(finalImage)
    });
}
```

Now call this function like this.

```
self.getIMG { (image) in
    //Access the image object
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, am going to experiment now and will get back to you . cheers

Comment: also, even when I do put a break point on  `finalImage = imageObj!.image;` the value still comes up as empty NSObject ... surely that means there is still another undylering problem?

Comment: Have you try with closure?

Comment: no, am writing now - but even so? will say result in a sec

Comment: Okay, i have updated it and it still returns an empty UIImage with NSObject

Comment: Nirav is telling you what you need to do. Your function getIMG can't return an image as it's function result if the image is loaded with an async method. You need to refactor it to take a closure as a parameter. If the changes Nirav have suggested aren't working, edit your question to show the new code at the end, along with a description of what you're seeing now.

Comment: Try to print the image object in closure, if it is still not working then may be the issue is with your `MKMapSnapshotter` method.